# getting err_empty_response on pdf download php

Tags: php, pdf, download

I am a beginner in PHP and I do not understand the reason for the problem.

Sometimes the `'err_empty_response'` error occurs when I try to download a PDF file.

```
<a href="../files/257.615.525-15_111731584_PUBLIC_20150305_115353.pdf" target="_blank">
```

- Microsoft Windows Server 2003 Enterprise Edition Service Pack 2
- RAM: 4GB
- CPU: 4 cores
- Pdf size: 72.135kb

Comment: The file `257.615.525-15_111731584_PUBLIC_20150305_115353.pdf` exist ?

Comment: yes. the problem is intermittent

Comment: I'm not seeing what this has to do with PHP

Comment: So how can we help you ?

Comment: Use the developer mode on your browser to inspect the traffic.

Comment: @PatrickQ That was my main suspicion. I think it's a problem with the infrastructure. But as I do not know very well of PHP I decided to ask for help to try to assemble arguments.

Comment: @jdv As the problem is intermittent , when the error occurs in the use, when he opening the Network tab there is no record. In theory the Developer Tools should be opened before the error happens. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @PabloSouza yes. You just have to find a way of reproducing and inspect the traffic when it you do. It's unclear to me where this error is being raised. If in the browser then who knows.

Comment: @jdv I tried a stress test with Jmeter with 50 concurrent users on my local machine and the error did not happen.

Comment: Since this isn't actually a programming question, you may (although I couldn't say for sure) have better luck on one of the other StackExchange sites.  Stack Overflow is really geared towards fixing problems with code that you've written.

Comment: Then it probably isn't related to load. Perhaps timing. But it is unclear how any PHP code is related to this. There is no [mcve] and a user-agent is getting an empty response at some point? This is a tricky problem but appears to be off topic for SO.

Comment: OK!. No problem! Tks for your help! How can I delete or close this?